# can we get the total email account configured in the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, email, ios5

I want total email accounts configured in the iPhone device. I have been searching a lot but i have not get any useful links. Can we get this information in iPhone(ios5) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

No there is no way the acces this information via the official SDK.